# How can I get line and column numbers of elements when parsing xml with Python?

Tags: python, xml, parsing

What I'm trying to do is write a GUI program in Python that displays the contents of XML files with some basic features like syntax highlighting (this isn't the only thing it needs to do, but it is one of the things).

To do this, I figured I should use an xml parsing package such as lxml or ElementTree. When I render the xml, I would like to be able to use the data structure produced by the parser to do things like syntax highlighting (or whatever). lxml has a "sourceline" property, but nothing for column numbers as far as I can tell.

Am I going about this the right way? Is there a better way to accomplish what I want? Otherwise I think will have to write my own XML parser, which I'm not enthusiastic about.

Comment: XML parsers are the right answer. You'd need to figure out what exactly "columns" as they look to you mean in the actual layout. Are you working with actual `<tr>` and `<td>` tags? Is it just a visual arrangement of `divs`? All you'd have to do is decide what is it that makes you think of column numbers, and count them using one of the functions that can get elements by name or some other property. You should not reinvent the wheel and try to make a new parser for this.

Comment: Oh, by "columns" in this context I mean character columns from the xml file itself. That is, I want a way to be able to take a node from the tree produced by the parser and ask "what line number and column does this tag start at?"

Comment: Isn't the column numbers is on a line the number of characters in that line?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. But what I want is a way to know what line and column number a given tag in the XML file starts on.